# Animate background with patternimage

Tags: swift

Im a bit stuck trying to animate my background transition in Swift.

I have set the `backgroundColor` of `selv.view` to contain a `UIColor` with `patternImage` so that my `backgroundColor` is actually an image. 
However, `animateWithDuration` doesnt seem to support a transition with this kind of element. Anyone got any tips?

```
selv.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( patternImage : UIImage( named: "A.png" ) )

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( patternImage: theCard.Background! )
})
```

As it is right now, it just delays 1 second and then switches without any transition.

Card.Bakground is defined in a Struct:

```
var Background: UIImage?

if let theBackground = theCard["Background"] as? UIImage {
    self.Background = theBackground
}
```

The struct is populated with a dictionary as exampled:

```
let letters : [[String : AnyObject?]] = [
    ["Title":"A", "Background": UIImage( named: "A.png" ), "Sound":NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("A", ofType: "wav")!), "AnimationObject":UIImage( named: "F-Frosk.png" )],
```

The whole animation sequence:

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
            theCard.Background!.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)
            var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( patternImage: image )
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
        })
```

This sequence is repeated when I swipe left / right in my PageView app to change the background of view. 
Just to be clear. The background of each "page" in my PageView is clear background, and the background image itself is appended to a ViewController which controls the PageView.

Comment: Can you confirm UIColor created out of this image is non nil?

Comment: I would suppose its not nil as it assigns the image to the backgroundcolor and it is displayed on the screen?

Comment: Just tried something similar and its animating in my case. Can we see how you declare  `card.Background!`

Comment: I updated my question to contain more information @zellb